# How to reduce number of points for clustering

Tags: clustering

**Description**

I have to find number of clusters for *1D data*. All clusters are assumed to have a gaussian distribution (so there is a big number of same points). I have a robust "agglomerative clustering + EM"-based algorithm which is able to find cluster centers.

**Problem**

The number of clusters varies (in different data sets) from $1$ to $10$, but number of points in my *1D* datasets varies from hundreds to hundreds of thousands. And that is the problem, because my algorithm is running pretty slow for high number of points.

**Questions**

Is there any simple method how to reduce number of points? The accuracy of cluster centers does not matter for me, I just only want to have fast detection.

Is it OK to select each k-th point and apply clustering algorithm on that selection. Or do I need something else like counting number of same points and leave out some percent of same points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to reduce your data set. Instead, you probably need to improve your implementation.

One-dimensional data should *not* be handled with the average clustering techniques. Because these techniques were designed for *multivariate* data.

**One-dimensional data is special.** It can be *sorted* consistently in $O(n \log n)$, and then you can use various algorithms in $O(n)$ time. A naive implementation of e.g. hierarchical ("agglomerative") clustering is $O(n^3)$ and that will of course kill you with large data. By any means *avoid distance matrixes*. They kill scalability.

1. Sort your data
2. Improve your algorithm to exploit this.

You may also want to look at classic statistical approaches for this problem, such as **kernel density estimation**. Consider using local density maxima as clusters.